# Django queryset filter performance

Tags: django, performance, django-models, django-queryset, django-cache

I have a queryset :-

```
queryset = my_object.someobject_set.all()
```

From there onwards, I want to filter from the queryset. i.e:

```
print queryset.filter(name='some1').exists()
print queryset.filter(name='some2').exists()
print queryset.filter(name='some3').exists()
```

But for each of the filter queries, there is a database hit again. How can I cache the queryset and then filter from it?

I even tried to evaluate the queryset before filtering by doing this:-

```
print len(queryset)
```

But this doesn't work.
Any help??

Comment: Or you meant that this are 3 different queries?

Comment: Yes I mean 3 different queries

Comment: Then fix your code in example

Comment: Already done. Please check again.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Are you want to get filtered querysets or just want to check existence?

Comment: Just check existance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible with django ORM. But you can do that in python.

```
queryset = list(my_object.someobject_set.all())

print list(filter(lambda i: i.name == 'some1', queryset))
print list(filter(lambda i: i.name == 'some2', queryset))
print list(filter(lambda i: i.name == 'some3', queryset))
```

This way you won't do any additional db hits. But if this queryset is really big than it is better to do it with ORM, even if it hits db. Time it for yourself and see which one is faster

Comment: no need to fetch all columns into memory. use `only` instead.

Comment: @itzmeontv I'm not sure that he just wants to check if values exists or not. But yes, if this needed only for checking `only` is way to go.

Comment: what you think of ? looping over lists and check for a field vs 'exists' query to db ?answer from your knowledge? :)

Comment: @itzmeontv are you asking in general?

Comment: yes, sometimes i am thinking doing `exist` is best than loop over.

Comment: @itzmeontv It really depends. Sometimes your DB located on another machine, so there will be network ping(should be taken to account). If there is millions of rows and DB on same server, then yes `exist` is probably faster. But for small querysets it is better to do in python. Because usually openning connections is very time expensive.